# Changing vendor.js file into gzip not working

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I have uploaded the code to s3 using production and aot flag but the site is loading very slowly so I searched the web and I gziped the vendor.js and polyfills.js.

Then I removed the gzip extension from the files and uploaded to the server.
And then I changed the metadata of both the files to this 
content-type:text/javascript
content-encoding:gzip
But I got the error as polyfils.js and vendor.js not found.
Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong or suggest any other way to decrease the loading time of my site

Comment: Take a step back.  Go directly to the URL of one of these files in your browser.  Do you see the code from the file displayed by the browser? You should.  Or do you see an error?  Troubleshoot from there.  There's nothing inherently related to gzipping the files that would result in "not found."